# Spring DelimitedLineTokenizer, how to disable de-escaping double quotes

Tags: spring, spring-batch

`org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer`, by default, "de-escapes" the fields. That means, it replaces two double quotes into one in the value. How can I stop this behavior? I need this because there is a next `DelimitedLineTokenizer` in the program misinterpreting this single double quote.
How can I do it? Could not get an answer from other posts.

I do have feature one value on multiple lines, because of that I cannot return false from `isQuoteCharacter`, as mentioned in some other posts. Here is the code.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="delimiter" ref="delimiter-#{jobExecutionContext['DELIMITER']}" />
                    <property name="names"
                        value="#{jobExecutionContext['COLUMNS_NAME_LOOKUP']}" />

                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean class="com.tsys.enterprise.converters.flexible.delimited.file.FlexibleDelimiterBasedFileParserFieldSetMapper"
                    scope="step">
                    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
                    <property name="targetType" value="com.tsys.enterprise.converters.flexible.delimited.file.vo.DataHolder"/>
                    
                    <property name="udfLabel1Label" value="#{jobExecutionContext['UDF1_LABEL']}"/>
                    </bean>
```

Comment: Please share a concrete example of the current behaviour and what you are expecting. What do you mean by "there is a next `DelimitedLineTokenizer`"? Please share your code to understand how data is flowing through out your app.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine There is a next DelimitedLineTokenizer means, in the code/application, there is another ItemReader which is reading data from memory read and processed by this reader. So two readers.

Comment: I'd urge create simple POC and share code in that case we should be able to help you!